# Why are recursive CTEs unable to use grouping and other clauses?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, recursion

I recently learned about Recursive Common Table Expressions (CTEs) while looking for a way to build a certain view of some data. After taking a while to write out how the first iteration of my query would work, I turned it into a CTE to watch the whole thing play out. I was surprised to see that grouping didn't work, so I just replaced it with a "Select TOP 1, ORDER BY" equivalent. I was again surprised that "TOP" wasn't allowed, and came to find that all of these clauses aren't allowed in the recursive part of a CTE:

- DISTINCT
- GROUP BY
- HAVING
- TOP
- LEFT
- RIGHT
- OUTER JOIN

So I suppose I have 2 questions:

1. In order to better understand my situation and SQL, why aren't these clauses allowed?
2. If I need to do some sort of recursion using some of these clauses, is my only alternative to write a recursive stored procedure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to :-

> 1. In order to better understand my situation and SQL, why aren't these clauses allowed?

Based on my understanding of CTE's, the whole idea behind creating a CTE is so that you can create a temporary result-set and use it in a **named** manner like a regular table in `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statements.

Because a CTE is logically very much like a view, the `SELECT` statement in your CTE query must follow the same requirements as those used for creating a view. Refer **CTE query definitions* section in following link on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Also, because a CTE is basically a named resultset and it can be used like any table in `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statements, you always have the option of using the various operators you mentioned when you use the CTE in any of those statements.

With regarding to

> 2.If I need to do some sort of recursion using some of these clauses, is my only alternative to write a recursive stored procedure?

Also, I am pretty sure that you can use at least some of the keywords that you have mentioned above in a **view** / **CTE select statement**. For Example: Refer to the use of `GROUP BY` in a CTE [here in the Creating a simple common table expression example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Maybe, if you can provide a sample scenario of what you are trying to achieve, we can suggest some possible solution.

Comment: Both links refer to the same webpage and I would not recommend it since it contains a lot of inconsistencies and bugs. Have you really run scripts from it? and read it? Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972(v=SQL.100).aspx instead

Comment: @vgv8 - Yes both links are to the same webpage - I was referring to the same page just different sections in my answer. Also, i was just asking the OP to see the example listed there for reference as to how to use the Group By. I am not aware of any inconsistencies there for the parts which i am referenced but if you can highlight those, that will help!!

Comment: In you link the script in section "C. Referencing a common table expression more than one time" does not reference CTE more than once. The following scripts do not run at all since engage nonexistent dbo.MyEmployees

Comment: @vgv8 - Actually, i was referring only to the example "Creating a simple common table expression" as specified in my reply as that is the one using a GROUP BY clause as the OP had posted the Group By cannot be used in a CTE. But your point noted!!